# Inserting a hyperlink into two different cells using the same criteria

Tags: excel, vba

This code looks at a cell named LoanProgram and inserts a hyperlink.

I want to assign a link to cell B18 and another link to cell C19.

The value it is searching for is "HOMEREADY/HOMEPOSSIBLE".

I tried using different criteria but it ignores the elseif statement.

```
If Range("LoanProgram").Value Like "*READY*" Then
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("C18"), Address:="https://homeready.com, TextToDisplay:="HOMEREADY"

ElseIf Range("LoanProgram").Value Like "*Possible*" Then
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("C19"), Address:="freddiemac.com", TextToDisplay:="HOMEPOSSIBLE"

end if
```

Comment: Could you show us the code that you tried? It would also be helpful that you show us the final result that you want to achieve. You mentioned that you want to assign a hyperlink to C18 and C19, but it seems that your code is already doing this.

Comment: The code I tried is the one shown, the code looks like it should work but it doesn’t, cell C18 works but C19 doesn’t get the hyperlink. I suspect it’s because the cell it’s evaluating has both values I’m searching for.

Comment: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to separate your conditions in two If's. In your original code, only one of the two If's gets executed even though LoadProgram contains both READY and POSSIBLE.

```
If Range("LoanProgram").Value Like "*READY*" Then
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("C18"), Address:="https://homeready.com, TextToDisplay:="HOMEREADY"
End If

If Range("LoanProgram").Value Like "*Possible*" Then
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("C19"), Address:="freddiemac.com", TextToDisplay:="HOMEPOSSIBLE"
End if
```

Comment: Sometimes the obvious isn't obvious, thanks, I can't believe I didn't think of that simple solution